# Merge two columns based on values present in first one

Tags: r

I have a data frame like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("X", "Y", "Z"), c("A/A", "B/B", "A/A"), c("D/D", "H/H", "B/B"))
```

I want to merge the columns in the following way,

If the second column has "B/B" keep it. If not, take the value from the third column.

How can this be done? I want the final output to just be the ID column and the merged second and third columns (as a single column) in a data frame.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# name the columns
names(df)[-1] <- letters[2:ncol(df)]

# create "merged" column with dplyr
require(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(newcol = replace(c, b == "B/B", "B/B")) %>% select(ID, newcol)

#create "merged" column with data.table
require(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, .(ID, newcol = replace(c, b == "B/B", "B/B"))]
```

Thanks to thelatemail for pointing out the obvious solution I somehow missed, which requires no packages

`cbind(df["ID"], newcol=replace(df$c, df$b == "B/B", "B/B"))`

Comment: Or without any packages - `cbind(df["ID"], newcol=replace(df$c, df$b == "B/B", "B/B"))`